# How to access a derived class member from const base class reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Base1{
    public:
        Base1(){};
        virtual ~Base1() = 0;
}

class Derived1 : public Base1{
    public:
        Derived1(int a) : a(a){};
        ~Derived1();
        int a;
}

class Base2{
    public:
        Base2(){};
        virtual ~Base2() = 0;
}

class Derived2 : public Base2{
    public:
        Derived2(int b) : b(b){};
        ~Derived2();
        int b;
        void func(const Base1 &base1); // How to access Derived1::a here?
}
```

Given the above class definition, how can I access `Derived1::a` in `void func(const Base1 &base1)`? I am still new to polymorphism. I tried to use different static_cast or dynamic_cast methods but none of them works. What should I do inside the function so I can access a derived class member from a base class reference?

FYI I can't change the class definition for my coursework requirement, and that is what given to me. I understand that it is simpler to just pass Derived1 as parameter but I am not allow to do so.

Comment: `Given the above class definition, how can I access Derived1::a in void func(const Base1 &base1)?` You don't. Your parameter should be a `Derived1`, not a `Base1`.

Comment: If you require `base1` to reference a `Derived1`, why is the parameter not `const Derived1&`?

Comment: You have a misunderstanding my guy. You cannot access members of a derived class from the base class. So just use `Derived1` instead of `Base1`.

Comment: You may access any virtual class member functions declared `const`, you also can use  a  `dynamic_cast<const Derived1&>(base1)`, but I'd not really recommend that.

Comment: I am asked to follow such a function definition in my coursework's skeleton codes so I don't get what should I do. @tkausl

Comment: @kyktyj - If that's what your coursework requires you to use, you should followup with your instructor.

Comment: @StephenNewell Ok, thanks for letting me know that it isn't a good programming practice.

Comment: Do what you have to do to pass the class. The instructor may get back to this later and explain why it's a bad idea or it may be covered in your course readings. If it isn't, you may want to upgrade your understanding of the language and idioms with some self-study and [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) to ease your entry into the workforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the above class definition, how can I access `Derived1::a` in `void func(const Base1 &base1)`? ... FYI I can't change the class definition for my coursework requirement, and that is what given to me.

Ideally, you should expose a `virtual` method in `Base1` that returns an `int` (or `int&`), and then have `Derived1` override that method to return its `a` member.

But, given that you are not allowed to change the class definitions, that is not an option.

You need a pointer or reference to a `Derived1` object in order to access its `a` member directly.  Which really leaves you with only 1 choice - you can use `dynamic_cast` to typecast the base class reference to the derived class type, eg:

```
void Derived2::func(const Base1 &base1)
{
    // this will raise an exception if the cast fails at runtime
    const Derived1 &d = dynamic_cast<const Derived1&>(base1);
    // use d.a as needed...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
void Derived2::func(const Base1 &base1)
{
    // this will return null if the cast fails at runtime
    const Derived1 *d = dynamic_cast<const Derived1*>(&base1);
    if (d) {
        // use d->a as needed...
    } else {
        // do something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `static_cast` if you are sure the object is a Derived1, and don't need the extra checking.